# Excluding results from joined tables based on a single count value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I'm joining, and would like to exclude any result that has a count greater than 1 for a value in the second table.

For this example, I have a table called `movie_info`, which has information about films, each with a unique ID. A second table called `crew_info` has information about each film's crew (with film's unique ID), but rather than 1 entry per film, there are multiple entries per crew member. Visually it would be like this:

```
+----------------------+
|       movie_info     |
+======================+
|       id  = '123'    |  
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|       crew_info      |
+======================+
|       id = '123'     |
+----------------------+
|     name = 'John'    |
+----------------------+
|   role = 'director'  |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|       crew_info      |
+======================+
|       id = '123'     |
+----------------------+
|     name = 'Mary'    |
+----------------------+
|   role = 'director'  |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|       crew_info      |
+======================+
|       id = '123'     |
+----------------------+
|      name = 'Sue'    |
+----------------------+
|     role = 'writer'  |
+----------------------+
```

I join the two tables like so:

```
SELECT a.id, b.*
FROM movie_info as a
LEFT JOIN crew_info as b
on a.id = b.id
```

So far it's all standard. What I'm trying to do though is *only* return results in which `crew_info` has a count of only 1 director. So a standalone query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM crew_info
WHERE role = 'director'
HAVING count(id) = 1
```

successfully excludes results like this example, where there is more than 1 director. But how exactly do I join this with the `movie_info` table, so that it's all in one query?

I'm sorry if this is unclear. I am relatively new to SQL so please let me know if there's anything I haven't expressed properly. Thank you.

**EDIT:** One more thing I forgot about, sorry! If the count *is* more than 1, how do I still include results if another value is matched? So let's say  `movie_info` also had a field called `sequel_id`, which is only filled out if the film is a sequel. I want to *exclude* results that have a director count > 1, AND an empty or null `sequel_id`, but *include* results that have a director count > 1 AND a valid `sequel_id` value. I tried something like `(HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 OR (HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND sequel_id IS NOT NULL))` but I'm getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your existing query as an EXISTS sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie_info
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM crew_info
    WHERE crew_info.id = movie_info.id
    AND crew_info.role = 'director'
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
OR sequel_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you! I just updated my question with an additional question that I forgot to include. Would you happen to know how to modify this to work for that case as well?

Comment: Just add `OR sequel_id IS NOT NULL` in the _outer_ query?

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using cte

```
with cte as
(
SELECT id
FROM crew_info
WHERE role = 'director'
HAVING count(id) > 1
) select a.*,b.id  FROM movie_info as a
LEFT JOIN cte as b
on a.id = b.id
```

without cte you can also subquery

```
select a.*,b.id FROM movie_info as a
left join (
          SELECT id
         FROM crew_info
         WHERE role = 'director'
         group by id
         HAVING count(id) > 1
          ) b on a.id=b.id
```